# How to turn all integers in an array into a single number?

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is my array

```
[7, 8, 8, 0, 0, 7, 2, 3, 1]
```

I know how to add all of these numbers together, but how do I make them into one long number? For example:

```
788007231
```

Comment: array.join("");

Comment: Just a heads up, if you want to treat this collapsed result as an `integer`, you'll have an issue if your array starts with a 0. Well, not an issue, but the 0 (or 0s) will be truncated.

Comment: let result= '';

[7, 8, 8, 0, 0, 7, 2, 3, 1].forEach((item)=>{
    result = result + item;
})
    
console.log(Number(result))